# How large is AppEngine's Private Key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, google

AppEngine provides methods for signing binary data - e.g. via the Go language's SignBytes[1]

However, it doesn't specify any information about how large the private key is.

Is this published somewhere - or is there some way of figuring it out?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference#SignBytes